# Storyboards UITableview with Custom Cell - Empty Array Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, afnetworking

I keep getting an error saying my table array is empty. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Set navigation bar image
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    spinnerActivity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    spinnerActivity.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    spinnerBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:spinnerActivity];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = spinnerBarButton;
    [spinnerActivity startAnimating];

    self.testString =       [[NSString alloc] init];
    self.testMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.myTableView =      [[UITableView alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:self.myTableView];

    [self getMoviesInformation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMenuBarButtonItem:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

#pragma mark - Custom Methods
- (void)getMoviesInformation
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=6844abgw34rfjukyyvzbzggz&q=The+Man+With+The+Iron+Fists&page_limit=1"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.testMutableArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"movies"];
        NSLog(@"Return String: %@", self.testMutableArray);
        [self.myTableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [operation start];
}

#pragma mark - Tableview Methods
#pragma mark DataSource
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"movieTableCell";

    MovieTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MovieTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.testMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Dict: %@", dict);
    cell.titleLabel.text = @"test";
    NSLog(@"Cell TitleLabel: %@", cell.titleLabel.text);

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark Delegate
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 150;
}
```

Here's the error message I'm encountering:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for
>   empty array

Any idea why my dictionary is always nil and what I should adjust in my code to make it work? I basically patterned this to the example here:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
self.testMutableArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"movies"];
```

to something like:

```
[self.testMutableArray addObject:(id)[JSON objectForKey:@"movies"]];
```

Your not adding in your objects to the array, your basically clearing it every time and assigning some object, that may or may not valid, to it. You need to consecutively add objects into the array if you want cellForRowAtIndexPath to work correctly.

Oh and the problem is not that your dictionary is nil. It's that your trying to grab a part of your array that doesn't exist/ hasn't had something assigned to it and assign that to your dictionary. Check your array count with `testMutableArray.count` to see how many objects you actually have in it.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it. UPDATE: It still returns the same error. :(

Comment: is the json object a single item or several?

Comment: Also in cellForRow, add this: if(indexPath.row < self.testMutableArray.count)

Comment: It's only for a single item for now. Once I get this to work, I'll populate it with other items.

Comment: Cool well before you do any objectAtIndex operations, just add in that if statement i wrote above. You will no longer crash and then u'll be able to debug from there. I suggest printing out your array count and indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore. Thanks. I'd like to add on how can I put the title text on my `cell.textLabel.text` after the dictionary has been populated? I actually populate it by `cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];` but don't know where to place it in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Anywhere inside of the indexPath.row < array.count if-statement would be fine. You could also do it inside of willDisplayCell if you'd like. I usually do it in cellForRow the same way you are though